# Algorithm to create numbers that are easy to memorize and difficult to mistake

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I want to assign numbers to people as their ID. As these numbers will have to be remembered, entered manually, and written on paper often, I would like to make sure that the numbers are selected to decrease the risk of misremembering or mistyping one person's ID and by accident typing some other person's ID. IDs must be numerical because they also must be encoded in barcode.

Smaller example: For 10 people using the numbers 1 to 10 makes it easy to mistype say 5 instead of 4. Instead, if people were assigned 16, 29, 31, 48, 57, 62, 75, 83, 94, this risk should be reduced as every number has no valid direct neighbors, any digit is unique in any position and misremembering another valid number is less likely.

In reality I need to assign numbers to 1000 people using numbers with six digits.

I am looking for an algorithm that can select these numbers. Preferably it would take into consideration both memorability and the risk of writing or inputting in another valid number by mistake. Unfortunately I cannot immediately describe how to measure these two factors. I was hoping that there exists some standard solution that I am just unable to find for the lack of keywords.

I have also thought about checksums but they do not work on paper. Assigning a second number to participants so a wrong input can be caught by the mismatch is not feasible and faces similar difficulties on paper.

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.

Comment: The ID has to be printed on tiny labels with barcodes which fit similarly tiny samples. At the same time, people have to fill out forms using their ID. It certainly isn't optimal but a solution is needed quickly.

Comment: It's still a bad design. People shouldn't need to remember numbers. That's what the barcode does. Don't make people do that too.

Comment: And quickly doesn't make it right.

Comment: Barcodes can represent more than numbers. Also computers are good at associating words with numbers. You could offer both.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the realm of [error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code) and [error detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) codes. Choose your [poison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Error_detection_schemes).

Simplest way would be to dedicate a digit as a [control digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit), which allows you to easily detect errors of one typo. For 1000 people and 6 digits (1,000,000 numbers) you can have 2 such digits and allow an easy detection of 2 typos.